# Выделение текста в textview курсивом через код

Tags: java, android, html, строки, textview

Как через `java` выделить текст?

Не жирным и курсивом, а например использовать `text-shadow`. Можно через `div`, или другой тег.

**Мой код:**

```
`text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` 
Spannable s = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(путь к тексту);
text.setText(s);
```

Текст хранится тут

```
  <string name="btn25javaA7"><![CDATA[ <a href="#ссылка">Текст обычный <div>текст особый</div></a> ]]>
```

Comment: java? не javascript?

Comment: java, android приложение

Comment: всё без вопросов. Сами понимайте как сейчас с этими терминами туго